# Discard match if it doesn't contain a specified keyword

Tags: c#, regex

Example text:

```
START
This is example example example example example example example example .
END
START
This is example 1234 14 756 214 6456 5 2 4234 66 match.
END
START
This is This isThis isThis isThis isThis isThis isThis isThis is.
END
```

I need to only match the text that is between "START" and "END" keywords and that contains word "match" in it.

I currently have this regex:

```
Regex.Matches(myString, @"START(.*?match.*?)END", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

It doesn't work correctly since it waits for "match" word to appear before matching "END" keyword:

```
This is example example example example example example example example .
END
START
This is example 1234 14 756 214 6456 5 2 4234 66 match.
```

How can I discard sentences between "START" and "END" keywords if they don't contain "match" word?

Comment: "RegexOptions.Singleline" - this does seem incorrect, given your example input and pattern.

Comment: @Fildor Perhaps a read of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options#Singleline might enlighten you as to why it's not as weird as it looks.

Comment: @spender Correct, not as weird as it seemed ... I still wouldn't use it here, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prevent the regex engine from crossing match boundaries; lazy quantifiers don't do that, but a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) can:

```
Regex.Matches(myString, @"START((?:(?!\bEND\b).)*match(?:(?!\bEND\b).)*)END", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/wDHqx7/1).

`(?:(?!\bEND\b).)*` matches any character (`.`), but only if it's not starting the `END` keyword `(?!\bEND\b)`. By enclosing that into a repeated non-capturing group `(?:...)*` we can make sure that this condition is tested on each character.

Answer (score 0):

I arrived at this solution, it seems simpler than the others. It allows any character other than the word END (. also includes newline in this case, but that's what singleline is for)

```
START((?!END).)*match((?!END).)*END
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. Yours solution works too, but I can only accept one answer :(.

Answer (score 0):

you sure that you want to use regex for that kind of task? you simply can solve it by :

```
        string mystring = "START This is example example example example example example example example. END START This is example 1234 14 756 214 6456 5 2 4234 66 match. END START This is This isThis isThis isThis isThis isThis isThis isThis is. END";
        string result = "";

        foreach(string text in mystring.Split(new string[] { "START", "END" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            if (text.Trim().Contains("match"))
            {
                result = text;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. I know it can be done otherwise, but I needed to use regex.